# Console logging prints a promise when function returns an object but prints the data when it is not an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, fetch-api

I have this function that makes a get request to an API:

```
const get = async (endpoint: string): Promise<object> => {
    const response: Response = await fetch(`${process.env.PROXY}/${endpoint}`, {
      method: "GET",
    });
    return {data: response.json() as object};
};
```

When I use this function on a buttons `onClick` handler:

```
onClick={() => {
            get(
              `apiroute`
            ).then((data: object) => {
              console.log("Retuned data", data.data);
            });
          }}
```

The console shows an a `promise<object>` not the actual data,
but when I switch my get function to:

```
const get = async (endpoint: string): Promise<object> => {
    const response: Response = await fetch(`${process.env.PROXY}/${endpoint}`, {
      method: "GET",
    });
    return response.json() as object
};
```

where it isn't returning an object around the data,
then access the data by:

```
onClick={() => {
            get(
              `apiroute`
            ).then((data: object) => {
              console.log("Retuned data", data);
            });
          }}
```

the console prints out the actual data.
Why does this happen? I would much prefer to do it the first way and add an extract key for `error` but this logging issue is really annoying me

Comment: `response.json()` returns a promse, that's why `data.data` is a promise.

Comment: ohhh i'm so stupid so if I just ```await``` the ```response.json()``` then I will be fine, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And when you return it directly, it works because promises to promises don't exist, they are always collapsed, so awaiting your function will implicitly also await the returned other promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first way:

```
const get = async (endpoint: string): Promise<object> => {
    const response: Response = await fetch(`${process.env.PROXY}/${endpoint}`, {
      method: "GET",
    });
    return {data: response.json() as object};
};
```

keep in mind that `response.json()` itself returns a promise.

So you're saying `return {data: <Promise>}`.

The reason that the second one works is because you're returning the promise directly in an async function,

```
const get = async (endpoint: string): Promise<object> => {
    const response: Response = await fetch(`${process.env.PROXY}/${endpoint}`, {
      method: "GET",
    });
    return response.json();
};
```

When you return a promise from an Async function, `get().then(...` resolves the promise like normal, so you're getting the proper data you expect out.

If you want to do the first way, `await` it first:

```
const get = async (endpoint: string): Promise<object> => {
    const response: Response = await fetch(`${process.env.PROXY}/${endpoint}`, {
      method: "GET",
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return {data: data};
};
```